# How to put a picture underneath another picture and centered?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if anyone knew how to have the download button picture under the album cover for all 4 pictures, as seen below in the code & the picture:

```html
<center>
    <img src="images/london-front-cover.jpg" alt="Londen front cover" width="200" height="200">
    <img src="images/london-volume.jpg" alt="Londen Volume (front cover)" width="200" height="200" border:none;>
    <img src="images/love-hate-volume.jpg" alt="Love Hate Volume (front cover)" width="200" height="200">
    <img src="images/gurbet-eli-volume.JPG" alt="Gurbet Eli Volume (front cover)" width="200" height="200">
    </br>
</center>
<a href="Londen-vol1.zip">
    <img src="images/downloadbutton.png" alt="downloadbutton" width="150" height="50">
</a>
</br>
</br>
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Just place the closing </center> tag below the closing </a> tag.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I want to have 4 download buttons underneath each picture centered

Comment: Please, consider to rename your pictures as well !!

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You can replace the anchor with an image or add an image inside the a tag.

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
.divWithBtn {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.divWithBtn img,
.divWithBtn a{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="divWithBtn">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
<a href="">download</a>
</div>
<div class="divWithBtn">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
<a href="">download</a>
</div>
<div class="divWithBtn">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
<a href="">download</a>
</div>
<div class="divWithBtn">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
<a href="">download</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And how can i center all of these images with that code ?

Comment: have a look at the css code. you can add another class to the div with `class="clear"` and set it to `margin: 0 auto;` The parent div should have `text-align: center;`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me, can you please paste the code with the center tag in it for the div in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to suggest you to learn the basics of a responsive css framework such as Bootstrap. You will get a lot of these kinks worked out when you use the right classes that are available to you. But even without bootstrap, learn the use of `text-align:center; float:left; display:block`. The combination of these will help you along your way.

Nonetheless, here is a working [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGpRJa) for ya

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: How is this a link only answer? Is a reference to the solution I built for him.  Codepen is no different than jfiddle,  only better.  Go check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `<center>` has been deprecated for a *long* time and should no longer be used. I'm surprised they're still teaching that.

Wrap each image and button in their own container and set the containers to `display:inline-block`.

The put all the containers in a master wrapper and apply `text-align:center`.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.divWithBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.divWithBtn img,
.divWithBtn a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <a href="">download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <a href="">download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <a href="">download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="divWithBtn">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <a href="">download</a>
  </div>
</div>
```